# Net::SSH2 authenticate using public key

Tags: perl, ssh, public-key-encryption, perlnetssh

I'm trying to use [Net::SSH2](https://metacpan.org/module/Net::SSH2) to execute commands on a remote machine. However, I do not know how to authenticate by using a public key. The documentation mentions this method:

```
auth_publickey ( username, public key, private key [, password ] )
```

However, it requires both a public key and a private key. Is there anyway that I can authenticate by just using a public key? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That makes no sense. "Everyone" has your public key. It can't be used to authenticate you.

Comment: you're right. I had a misunderstanding of what the two different keys were. I was able to figure it out now.